# Kallithea Push repo get error 500: internal server error

Tags: push, internal-server-error, kallithea

When I try to push my local repo to the Kallithea, I tried:

`hg push http://address of Kallithea repo`

After entering my password of Kallithea, I got the following error:

`abort: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error`

How to fix it?

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Comment: Your server logs should have details of what's causing the error. Those are very helpful in getting your problem solved!

Comment: Hi Greg, this may sounds stupid, but...where I can find the server logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)